# How to set the spf or 'sent via' in email header in php

Tags: php, email, phpmailer, html-email, email-headers

When you receive a email (in Gmail at least), you see the following format at the top: 'John Doe johndoe@gmail.com via servername.com' I am wondering if there is a way to change the 'servername.com' after the "via" while in doing so keeping my defined headers in my PHP code below, any help would be great:

```
<?php
    $to = 'johndoe@gmail.com';
    $message = 'blah';
    $subject = 'blahblah';
    $headers = 'From: test@gmail.com';
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
?>
```

Comment: You need to read this: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/1311182?hl=en Then fix your SPF records, implement DKIM.

Answer (score 0):

That's set by your MTA.  For Postfix I can tell you it's determined by the `myorigin` parameter in `main.cf`.

Comment: you can't. as I said, it's set by your MTA... which is?

Comment: Nope, this is a google thing relating to domain authentication.

Comment: @Synchro - I don't think so.  I run my own mailserver and if I change the `myorigin` setting in postfix the "**via example.com**" changes accordingly.  So as far as I can see it's simply a matter of how your mail transfer agent identifies itself during the initial handshake.

Comment: That is true, but it only adds the "via" notice if you fail to provide authentication for the domain, whatever it is.